# On orientation change activity with Fragment Crashes in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on an application in which I have used fragments. On calling web service on thread application crashes.
When Orientation changes, logs shows below exception in red color:

```
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270): Activity com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41457e20 that was originally added here
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41457e20 that was originally added here
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:268)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:117)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:100)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.HomeScreen.syncWithServer(HomeScreen.java:416)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.HomeScreen.onClick(HomeScreen.java:622)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3528)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14235)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-14 14:36:51.770: E/WindowManager(5270):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After this Activity is called again and due to flow of code, context fails to appear at alert box and application crashes.

```
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:78)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:111)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:100)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.HomeScreen$1.dispatchMessage(HomeScreen.java:141)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-14 14:37:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Either it should not call to the Activity again or the flow should stop at the moment.

Please suggest me in case of this fragment use, what should I do to handle my webservices.
Below is my code:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener,IServerResponse
{

    private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.arg2) {
            case Constant.PID_GETUPDATEDATA:
                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen.this.getActivity(),"", Constant.MSG_SYNC);
                final String msgData = (String) msg.obj;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        try{
                            if (msgData.equalsIgnoreCase("We apologize, no data was found.")) {

                                HomeScreen.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,
                                                Constant.MSG_NOUPDATE, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(), false);       
                                    }
                                });

                            }else{
                                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(msgData);
                                JSONObject electricObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
                                JSONArray electricDBArray=electricObject.getJSONArray("Electrical_DB");

                                int count=electricDBArray.length();

                                String PrivousDateTime=myPref.getString("PREVIOUS_DATETIME", "");
                                if(PrivousDateTime.equals("")||PrivousDateTime==null)
                                {                                                   
                                    _eCatalogueTable.deleteTable(ECatalogueDatabase.DATABASE_TABLE);
                                }

                                for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                                {
                                    String productLineID=electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id");
                                    String productLine=electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("productline");
                                    String hp = electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("outputhp");
                                    String rpm = electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("rpm");
                                    String voltage = electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("voltage");
                                    String frame = electricDBArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("frame");
                                    if(!isProductIDPresentInDb(productLineID))
                                    {                           
                                        _eCatalogueTable.InsertECatalogue(productLineID,productLine,hp, rpm, voltage, frame);
                                    }else
                                    {
                                        _eCatalogueTable.updateECatalogue(productLineID,productLine, hp, rpm, voltage, frame);
                                    }
                                }       

                                HomeScreen.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_SUCCESS,Constant.MSG_SUCCESS, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(), false); 
                                        findGMTDateTime();
                                        _mEditPref=myPref.edit();
                                        _mEditPref.putString("PREVIOUS_DATETIME", dateTimeValue);
                                        _mEditPref.commit();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            HomeScreen.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,
                                            Constant.MSG_SERVER_FAIL, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(), false);        
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        progressDialog.cancel();
                    }

                }).start();
                break; 
            case Constant.PID_ALERTDIGLOG:
                Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,Constant.MSG_SERVER_FAIL, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(),false);
                break;

            }
        };
    };

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen , container, false);

        _eCatalogueTable=new ECatalogueDatabase(HomeScreen.this.getActivity());
        _eCatalogueTable.open();

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            _headetRelativelayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
            _headetRelativelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            saveState="SavedInstance";
            rotateSaveInstace=true;
            Constant.checkPdf=false;
            //Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),"savedInstaceState", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
            saveStateBoolea=true;
            saveState="NoSavedInstance";
            //  Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),"No savedInstaceState", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        _productText=(TextView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.productline_txt);
        _hpText=(TextView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.hp_txt);
        _rpmText=(TextView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.rpm_txt);

        _voltageText=(TextView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.voltage_txt);
        _frameSizeText=(TextView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.frame_txt);

        _searchBypartEditText=(EditText)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.searchpart_edittxt);

        _searchButton=(Button)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.serach_btn);
        _searchButton.setEnabled(false);
        _searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _syncButton=(Button)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
        _syncButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _productSpinner=(Spinner)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.productline_spinner);
        _productSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _hpSpinner=(Spinner)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.hp_spinner);
        _hpSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _rpmSpinner=(Spinner)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.rpm_spinner);
        _rpmSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _voltageSpinner=(Spinner)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.voltage_spinner);
        _voltageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _frameSpinner=(Spinner)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.frame_spinner);
        _frameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _productRealtiveLayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.product_layout);
        _productRealtiveLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        _hpRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.hp_layout);
        _hpRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        _rpmRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.rpm_layout);
        _rpmRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        _voltageRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.voltage_layout);
        _voltageRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        _framSizeRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        _framSizeRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        useTextwatcher();

        _mHPArrayList.add(0, getString(R.string.hp_txt));
        _mRPMArrayList.add(0, getString(R.string.rpm_txt));
        _mVoltageArrayList.add(0,getString(R.string.voltage_txt));
        _mFrameSizeLineArrayList.add(0,getString(R.string.frame_txt));

        _productSpinner.setSelection(0);
        _hpSpinner.setSelection(0);

        _rpmSpinner.setSelection(0);
        _voltageSpinner.setSelection(0);
        _frameSpinner.setSelection(0);

        fetchProductLineFromDatabase();

        _productLineArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,_mProductLineArrayList);

        _hpArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,_mHPArrayList);
        _rpmArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,_mRPMArrayList);
        _voltageArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,_mVoltageArrayList);
        _frameSizeArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,_mFrameSizeLineArrayList);

        _productSpinner.setAdapter(_productLineArrayAdapter);
        _hpSpinner.setAdapter(_hpArrayAdapter);
        _rpmSpinner.setAdapter(_rpmArrayAdapter);
        _voltageSpinner.setAdapter(_voltageArrayAdapter);
        _frameSpinner.setAdapter(_frameSizeArrayAdapter);


        // GMT Date Time
        date=new Date();
        simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        myPref=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String PrivousDateTime=myPref.getString("PREVIOUS_DATETIME", "");
        boolean firstCheckAlert=myPref.getBoolean("FIRST_ALRT", firstTimeShowAllert);
        if(!firstCheckAlert)
        {
            showMessageAlert();
        }
        if(PrivousDateTime.equals("")||PrivousDateTime==null)
        {
            dateTimeValue= "01/01/2012 00:00:00";
        }else
        {
            dateTimeValue=PrivousDateTime;
        }
        return mContentView;
    }

    private void syncWithServer() {


        if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(HomeScreen.this.getActivity()))
        {

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen.this.getActivity(),"",Constant.MSG_SYNC);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String response = "";
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WebServiceDetails.SERVICENAMESPACE,WebServiceDetails.METHOD_CHECKLATESTDATADATE);
                    request.addProperty("lastmodifieddate",dateTimeValue);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(WebServiceDetails.URL);
                    httpTransport.debug = true;
                    try {
                        httpTransport.call(WebServiceDetails.SOAP_CHECKLATESTDATADATE, envelope); // send

                        Object data = envelope.getResponse();
                        if (data instanceof SoapObject) {
                            SoapObject data2 = (SoapObject) data;
                            response = data2.toString();
                        } else if (data instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
                            SoapPrimitive data3 = (SoapPrimitive) data;
                            response = data3.toString();
                        } else if (data != null) {
                            response = data.toString();
                        } else if (data == null) {
                            response = "nodata";
                        }
                        serverResponse(response,Constant.PID_GETUPDATEDATA);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        serverResponse(null,Constant.PID_ALERTDIGLOG);
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        else {
            Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,Constant.MSG_INTERNETERROR, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(),false);
        }

    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        fetchTextvalue();
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.serach_btn:
            if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(HomeScreen.this.getActivity())){
                FragmentManager fm = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                int count=fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
                System.out.println("gdfgdgcvbccccccccccccccccccc "+count);
                for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {    
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
                fetchTextvalue();


                if(!(_fetchProductText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.product_txt))||_fetchHpText.equalsIgnoreCase( getString(R.string.hp_txt))
                        ||_fetchRPMText.equalsIgnoreCase( getString(R.string.rpm_txt))||_fetchVoltageText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.voltage_txt))
                        ||_fetchFrameSizeText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.frame_txt))))
                {
                    if(_mGetEditValue.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.enterpart_txt))||_mGetEditValue==null)
                    {
                        dataSheetCall();
                    }else
                    {
                        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR, Constant.MSG_ENABLESEARCH, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(), false);
                        _searchBypartEditText.setText("");
                        _searchButton.setEnabled(true);
                        _mGetEditValue=(getString(R.string.enterpart_txt));
                    }
                }else if((!_mGetEditValue.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.enterpart_txt)))||_mGetEditValue!=null)
                {
                    if((_fetchProductText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.product_txt))&&_fetchHpText.equalsIgnoreCase( getString(R.string.hp_txt))
                            &&_fetchRPMText.equalsIgnoreCase( getString(R.string.rpm_txt))&&_fetchVoltageText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.voltage_txt))
                            &&_fetchFrameSizeText.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.frame_txt))))
                    {
                        dataSheetCall();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR, Constant.MSG_ENABLESEARCH, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(), false);
                        _searchBypartEditText.setText("");
                        _searchButton.setEnabled(true);
                        resetValue();

                    }
                }
            }else{
                Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,Constant.MSG_INTERNETERROR, HomeScreen.this.getActivity(),false);
                _productSpinner.setSelection(0);
            }

            break;          



            case R.id.sync_btn:
        syncWithServer();

        break;
        default:
            break;
        }       
    }

    private void dataSheetCall()
    {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Intent datasheetIntent=new Intent(this.getActivity(),DataSheetScreenActivity.class);
            datasheetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("PRODUCTLINE", _productString);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("HP", _hpString);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("RPM",_rpmString);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("VOLTAGE", _voltageString);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("FRAMESIZE", _frameSizeString);
            datasheetIntent.putExtra("PART NUMBER", _mGetEditValue);
            Constant.putAllValue(_productString, _hpString, _rpmString, _voltageString, _frameSizeString,_mGetEditValue);
            startActivity(datasheetIntent);
        } else {

            if(saveStateBoolea)
            {
                ImageFragment rightFrag = (ImageFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("imageFragmentTag");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(rightFrag);
                ft.commit();
                saveStateBoolea=false;
            }else if(saveState.equalsIgnoreCase("SavedInstance")&&(rotateSaveInstace==true))
            {
                ImageFragment rightFrag = (ImageFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("imageFragmentTag");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(rightFrag);
                ft.commit();
                rotateSaveInstace=false;
            }

            DataSheetScreenFragment dataSheetFragment = new DataSheetScreenFragment();
            fragmentTransaction = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.top_right_datasheet_relative_layout, dataSheetFragment, "rightDrawingFragmentTag"); //First parameter is the container id
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("1");
            fragmentTransaction.show(dataSheetFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            Constant.putAllValue(_productString, _hpString, _rpmString, _voltageString, _frameSizeString,_mGetEditValue);

            _pdfIcon=(ImageButton)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pdf_icon);
            _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            _pdfText=(TextView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pdf_txt);
            _pdfText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        resetValue();
    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "No select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        _eCatalogueTable.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!Constant.checkPdf)
        {
            _productSpinner.setSelection(0);
        }

    }

    public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.arg2 = processid;
        msg.obj = response;
        _handler .sendMessage(msg);     
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the Dialog you created in `ViewRootImpl.java` before exiting the Activity.

**EDITED:**

see your Error is Saying Below :

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41457e20 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
```

so Each View have a reference to their parent Context as you are passing constructor. If you leave an Activity without destroying Dialogs and other activity dynamically creat views, they still hold this reference to your Activity (if you created with `this` as Context: like `new ANY(this)`), so it will **not be collected by the GC, causing a memory leak**.

Comment: Thanks bhavesh....your suggestion worked for me.
I have dismiss the dailogs and after that I need to manage my code a bit, to add few context checks in if cases and finally I, means we resolved the issues:) Thanks

Comment: @samintechvalens: Welcome always :)

Answer (score 0):

add into activity tag in android manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".activityname"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: thread into thread conflict may be yo can use synchronization of thread maybe helpfull to you.